# How to paste date in the right format?

Tags: java, sqlite

The SqLiteStudio shows that the `date` field is type of TEXT but after I ran the code I found in database in the date field: `1994`
Why the value is not `2017-05-18` ?

```
stmt = c.createStatement();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = df.format(new Date());    
String sql = "UPDATE advert SET date = " + date + " WHERE advert_id=" + advertId + ";";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing single quotes around the date string, so it is interpreted as mathematical operation: 2017 - 5 - 18 = 1994.

Quote the date string:

```
String sql = "UPDATE advert SET date = '" + date + "' WHERE advert_id=" + advertId + ";";
                                       ^            ^
```

or better yet, use [prepared statements and parameter binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).